# Why is my iOS app second build, uploaded in apple store connect as a different app?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

So I decided to continue the development of the (react-native) app in an external ssd drive.

Thus, I cloned the app from GitHub, run `npm i` and `cd ios pod install`, run the app in a simulator and then made an Archive an uploaded to apple store connect.

But when I visited the apple store connect, I saw that the build was uploaded as another app with the same name.

I tried to copy/paste the ios folder of the old app into the new. Deleted the build folder and the DerivedData, made the Archive etc, but the new build was uploaded again in the second app.

Is there something that I'm not doing right?

I could delete the old app (in apple store connect) and go on with the new, (it's not in production yet) but I just wonder, why is this happening, and how can I avoid it.

Thank you

Comment: On the screen before upload , was the app name and version correct ? Did you first create the new version in App Store Connect ?

Comment: The app name is correct. The version though says 1.0 (5). The first part is correct, but the second shows the number of the last build I uploaded, which is not correct because I named this build (2).

Comment: And No, I didn't create any of the apps in App Store Connect. They were both uploaded through Xcode.

Comment: As I see, the Bundle ID and the SKU of the one app has a dash in the middle. Like: old is `com.coolapp` new is: `com.cool-app`.

Comment: I think it must this.

Comment: But in Xcode, the Bundle Identifier is the old one: `com.coolapp`. I haven't changed that.

Comment: Did search in the full project for a cool-app string ?

Comment: This is strange: In the old app, I have in `Info.plist` for key: `CFBundleIdentifier` a string with: `com.apple.xcode.dsym.com.cool-app`. Why is the dash there?. And in the cloned app, I have a string with: `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`. I replaced the string of the cloned with the one of the old one, but the Archive was rejected saying: *you can not have a `com.apple`* so I removed it, but got rejected again.